# Decompressing zlib compressed data using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, zlib, sharpziplib

I am looking at the following line of c++ code, where "zlib.h" is included

```
int err = compress2(compressed.get(), &dest_len,
                            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(plain_text.c_str()),
                            source_len, 9);
```

I am trying to undo this compression using C#. I figure I should use a C# library because writing my own decompression algorithm seems wasteful and difficult.
The library I have seem recommended is SharpZipLib (even by Mark Adler himself!)
However, it seems like compress2 with these args is using a preset dictionary. Here is my attempt at decompressing:

```
Inflater inflater = new Inflater(false);
inflater.SetInput(bytes);
int ret = inflater.Inflate(outBuffer, 0, 2047);
if (ret == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inflater.IsNeedingDictionary);
    Console.WriteLine(inflater.IsNeedingInput);
    Console.WriteLine(inflater.Adler);
}
```

This says it needs a dictionary. I know how to set the dictionary, but I am clueless about how to set it based on the zlib.h compress function. **How can I create the necessary preset dictionary to decrypt?**

Notes:
Here is the line of code I am trying to essentially replicate in C#

```
int err = uncompress(uncompressed.get(), &dest_len, plain_text.get(), src_len);
```

Where uncompressed is empty, dest len is simply 4*src_len, and src_len is compressed length. Compressed text stored in plain_text.

Here are the detected first 2 bytes in my C# program:
78 3f
(0111 1000  0011 1111)

Someone indicated that this doesn't make sense given the compress2 code given...

Sorry for any mistakes in my question, I haven't asked many questions on here.

Comment: I did not write SharpZipLib.

Comment: I understand that, you recommended it on another stackoverflow post a while back. Didn't mean to try and summon you here or anything was just trying to establish that at least some people thought the library was useful. Sorry for any misunderstanding! Looking into your answer now

Comment: Update: Accidentally converted the bytes using an ASCII encoding (which in C#, anything it doesn't expect it just sets to 63 (base 10). Very frustrating but hopefully this helps someone in the future. If this should be deleted I will do that.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, `compress2()` does not use a dictionary. Your data may not be making it over intact. You should put the first several bytes of what you're trying to decompress, as seen on the C# side, in hex in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is trying to use compress2 from zlib, and trying to deal with this input in C#, beware how you take in the compressed data. Compress2() does **not** use a preset dictionary.

Specifically, make sure that the first 2 bytes make sense. I shrugged off a strange second byte because the first byte was correct, but really read it and compare against the [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)

There are many ways to properly read the bytes, but my mistake was trying to read them using Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes. Don't do that!